# How to create a range of float values in python?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to do several loops inside each other with a condition of x+y+z should be equal to 1, to enter the last loop.

I used the following:

```
import numpy as np
for gbrCount in np.arange(0, 1.0, 0.1):
    for xgbCount in np.arange(0, 1.0, 0.1):
        for regCount in np.arange(0, 1.0, 0.1):
            #check if sum is 1
            if int(gbrCount+xgbCount+regCount) == 1:

                y_p = (xgbCount*xgb.predict(testset)+ gbrCount*gbr.predict(testset)+regCount*regressor.predict(testset))
                testset['SalePrice']=np.expm1(y_p)
                y_train_p = xgb.predict(dataset)
                y_train_p = np.expm1(y_train_p)
                rmse.append(np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y, y_train_p)))
                rmse.append(xgbCount)
                rmse.append(gbrCount)
                rmse.append(regCount)
```

But even if the sum was bigger than 1, it will enter the loop. Some of the values of (xgb, reg and gbr) are like 0.70000001.

So I tried to use linspace but it didn't work with floats. So I tried the range:

```
for gbrCount in range(0, 1):
    gbrCount += 0.1
    for xgbCount in range(0, 1):
        xgbCount += 0.1
        for regCount in range(0, 1):
            regCount += 0.1
            if int(gbrCount+xgbCount+regCount)==1:
                #y_p = (xgbCount*xgb.predict(testset)+ gbrCount*gbr.predict(testset)+regCount*regressor.predict(testset))
                #testset['SalePrice']=np.expm1(y_p)
                y_train_p = (xgbCount*xgb.predict(dataset)+ gbrCount*gbr.predict(dataset)+regCount*regressor.predict(dataset))
                y_train_p = np.expm1(y_train_p)
#                print(np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y, y_train_p)))
#                print(xgbCount)
#                print(gbrCount)
#                print(regCount)
                print(xgbCount,  gbrCount, regCount, np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y, y_train_p)))
```

But it didn't work with no error at all at the console.

Comment: You could loose the third loop and have something like `gbrCount = np.round(gbrCount, decimals=1`,`gbrCount = np.round(xgbCount, decimals=1`, and `regCount = np.round(1 - gbrCount - xgbCount, decimals=1)`.

Comment: Question has actually nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (please edit & remove).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this? (I don't think the last rounding is necessary, but just to be on the safe side I left it there.)

```py
    import numpy as np
    for _gbrCount in np.arange(0, 1.0, 0.1):
        for _xgbCount in np.arange(0, 1.0, 0.1):
            gbrCount = np.round(_gbrCounr, decimals=1)
            xgbCount = np.round(_cgbCount, decimals=1)
            regCount = np.round(1 - gbrCount - xgbCount, decimals=1)
            y_p = (xgbCount*xgb.predict(testset)+ gbrCount*gbr.predict(testset)+regCount*regressor.predict(testset))
            testset['SalePrice']=np.expm1(y_p)
            y_train_p = xgb.predict(dataset)
            y_train_p = np.expm1(y_train_p)
            rmse.append(np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y, y_train_p)))
            rmse.append(xgbCount)
            rmse.append(gbrCount)
            rmse.append(regCount)
```